# An object disappears after packing a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, packing

I have created a JavaScript library and packed it with these options selected : `Shrink Variables` and `Base62 Encoded` at this url: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/. In this library I have declared an object `ax`, but when I use the packed version in my web page I get an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: ax is not defined`.

The original code of this library looks like below.

```
var ax = {
     scaleUp:function(win) {
          //code omitted
       },
downGrade:function(win) {
        //code omitted
     }
}
```

In my web page in which I am using this library, I have code like below. This code works, if instead of packing, I minify it using Microsoft's Minifier or just use the original JavaScript library without minification or packing.

```
var result = ax.downGrade(w);
```

**Question** : 
Why is the variable `ax` not accessible with packed version? Do I need to add something else when using the packed version?

**UPDATE 1**:

I could not get the packed file to work  but packing my code through another compression utility at following url worked in my case: http://jsutility.pjoneil.net/.  It provided an equally good compression.

I am still not sure why the utility at  original url failed to produce a working version of my library, even though my original code works without any errors on any web page.

Comment: Look at the packed JavaScript and figure out where `ax` has gone. You haven't provided any code that reproduces the problem, so we cannot help.

Comment: How are you linking the packed script?

Comment: My library is huge with  a size of about 56 KB in its original state and about 16 KB in a packed state. That's why I did not provide my library, but it has code like  I have posted here.

Comment: @Jasen, I just used the packer at this link  http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ with base62 encoded and shrink variables selected. Do I need to link this packed script? May be that's what I am missing.

Comment: Is your library in separate files? Does one/some of the files depend on `ax`? If so, you need to repack it so that `ax` is packed first.

Comment: No, the code is all in a single js file before packing.

Answer (score 1):

Check your console for errors before trying to call ax. Explicitly place semi-colons where they belong.Example at the end of the definition for `ax` you should put a semi-colon, even though in standard code it's good as is. Remove the explicit `var` declarations. When I did these things:

```
ax = {
     scaleUp:function(win) {
          alert("up");
       },
downGrade:function(win) {
        alert("down");
     }
};
result = ax.downGrade();
```

Ran without issue in jsFiddle and console: http://jsfiddle.net/7kdnw65n/. I suspect it has to do with how the algorithm "shrinks" the variables. The resulting pack was:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[c]=k[c]||c;k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('0={5:1(2){3("6")},4:1(2){3("7")}};8=0.4();',9,9,'ax|function|a|alert|downGrade|scaleUp|up|down|result'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Ok. I will try your suggestions and let you know.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, but still the same error. I am using the packed file in asp.net by using this tag: <script src="~/Scripts/Lib1Packed.js">. It seems its some other problem, even though the original version gives no errors when used in same web page.

Comment: Try starting with the shortest possible version, like with the snipit that you provided. Don't make the call to ax just bring it in. See if there are errors. Then add a call to a short method that alerts something. Then continually add functionality. It will take a lot of time but you will eventually get to where the issue is so you can fix.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could not get it to work, so I tried an alternative packing utility at this url: http://jsutility.pjoneil.net/, and the compressed file from this url worked perfectly. So I suspect, that the the packing utility at original url was messing up my code somehow.